# JQuery JCarousel slider does not show up in IE7

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

in my web application JCarousel images loading in real time. Take a look
at the code (I typed it from hand, my real world app is more complex, but I hope you'll get the main idea):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* 
     * Get carousel
     *
     *@param int, start slide index 
     *@param json, images data in jason format
     *
     *@return nothing
    */  
    function showSlider(startSlide,photosJason){

        photosJason = eval(photosJason);

        html = '<ul id="mycarousel">';      

        for(i=0; i < photosJason.length; i++){

            html +=  '<li>' + 

            '<div class="image-title">' + 
                     photosJason[i].name +                        
                    '<div class="image-title-author">'+ photosJason[i].author +'</div>' + 
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="slider-image">' + 
                    '<img src="'+photosJason[i].photo+'" alt="" />' +  
                '</div>' +
              '</li>';      
        }

        html += '</ul>';                      

        $("#carousel-container").html(html); //also used append method instead of html

        $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            start: startIndex,
            visible: 1,
            scroll: 1,
            itemFallbackDimension: 800 //this is for IE7, to define the width
        });
    }
</script>

// skipped some php code to get photos data from database and convert it to jason format

<img src="some_img.jpg" alt="Show slider" onclick="showSlider(1,photosJason);" />

<div id="carousel-container"></div>
```

It works perfectly in all major browsers, except IE7. It seems like JCarousel 
can't find images dynamically loaded into container. So simply I don't get 
nothing but a blank screen. No errors, just nothing.

So what I suppose to do? Do I have to preload images or something ? I keep 
banging my head for all day and still don't get it how to make it work in IE7 (IE8 works ok).

I would be appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think IE7 can't `eval` your string.

Try this:

```
photosJason = $.parseJSON(photosJason);
```

How does your JSON look like?

Comment: With Json everything is ok. I checked it with $("#carousel-container").html(html); (without calling jcarousel class), so I get pretty nice list with all data from json. I guess problem is with JCarousel.

Comment: This is something like an Ajax response, you don't do it on page load but afterwards. Check this url http://www.snaver.net/2011/01/20/applying-jcarousel-to-ajax-loaded-content/

Comment: Thanks for example. Actually I don't use the Ajax in my situation.I think JCarousel in IE7 does not find the dynamically loaded images. Because if I put my carousel list to $(document).ready and then call JCarousel - it works like charm. In my situation I use JavaScript instead of Ajax. On the first load I take some data from php and pull it to JavaScript function. Is it possible to simulate document.ready in my JavaScript function? Or something ?

Comment: In the example I posted (the URL), they use Ajax, but you don't use ajax but load your JCarousel after document ready. What if you put your `$("#carousel-container").html(html)` after the `.JCarouse()` function.